# how to load form based on other form data using PHP and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm kinda new with php and ajax, so I need a little bit of help here. I'll explain my concept a little bit, please give me feedback is it possible or not.

this is a little bit of my code for the main page :

```
<ul class="treeview-menu">
    <li id = 'menu1'>
        <a>
            <i class="fa fa-angle-double-right"></i>
            Menu1
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div id="content_info" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="content_data" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="content_input" style="display:none;"></div>
```

I have two other page, lets called it `form_view.php` and `form_input.php`. the `form_view.php` is used to show data from the database, and the `form_input` is used to input new data and edit old data. I'm planning to use AJAX for loading the `form_view` and `form_input` on the main page.

First, when I choose `Menu1`, it will show the `content_data` div and hide the other two div. Then, it will load `form_view.php` inside the `content_data` div. I'm using tables for viewing the data and there's an edit button for each row. When I click the button, the form will be submitted to `form_input`, and the `form_input` will show the data that's been chosen.

Is it possible to make `form_input` show the data that's been chosen and load it in the `content_input` div? When this is happens, `content_data` and `content_info` will be hidden, and `content_input` will be shown. Is it possible to not refresh the main page while doing so?

And if it's all possible, can you show me some example for the code?

I appreciate any feedback. Thanks.

Comment: can you add the code for form_view.php and form_input.php

Answer (score 1):

Encode the data in the url request for `form_view.php`

```
$( "#content_data" ).load( "ajax/form_view.php?"+parameters );
```

Make sure to url encode your parameters.  The later retrieve the data from `$_GET` in your PHP.

Comment: I have posted a [quesiton](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63534630/8868582) related to it can you please check?